# Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL... Flask redirection from not working

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to create a web side using html, Javascript, python, Flask and MySQL. However, I have bumped into trouble when trying to follow tutorial online. The issue comes when trying to process a form from a html index page.
My app

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from datetime import datetime
import yaml
import smtplib
app = Flask(__name__)

db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = ''

@app.route('/')
def home():
    title = "Cheam Squash Ladders"
    return render_template("index.html", title=title)

@app.route('/sigin', methods=["POST"])
def form():
    user = request.form.get("user")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    return render_template("signin.html", title=title)

    user1 = request.form.get("user1")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password1 = request.form.get("password1")
    confirm_email = request.form.get("confirm")
    return render_template("register.html")


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

End in the error message from the title after inputing the form information. I'm running my virtual environment in a folder "MyNewFlaskApp" and this folder contains a "templates" folder and a "static" folder and I have run the app.py both from inside the virtual environment folder and from outside but nothing worked. All folders containing the htmls (tamplates) and the statics are outside the env. I am wondering if this is the issue.
I have search for days now without any luck.
Also, I'm running Python3 on a mac with Catalina.
Hope anyone can help.
Thanks in advance either way

```js
 <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("Signin");
    var y = document.getElementById("register");
    var z = document.getElementById("btn");
    
    function register(){
        x.style.left = "-400px";
        y.style.left = "50px";
        z.style.left = "110px";
    }
    function Signin(){
        x.style.left = "50px";
        y.style.left = "450px";
        z.style.left = "0px";
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form id="Signin" class="Signin-group" action="/signin" method="POST">
                <input id="username" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" name="user" required>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" required>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>Remember password</span>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick="login()">Sign In</button>
            </form>
 <form id="register" class="register-group" action="/register" method="POST">
                <input id="newUser" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" name="user1" required>
                <input id="newEmail" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                <input id="newPassword" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" name="password1" required>
                <input id="passwordConfirm" type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm" required>
                <div class="optionS"><input id="optionS" type="radio" name="sport" value="Squash" required> Squash
                    <input id="optionS" type="radio" name="sport" value="Racquetball" required> Racquetball
                    <br/><input type="checkbox" class="check-boxR" required><span class="checkboxR"> I agree to terms and conditions</span>
                </div> 
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" onclick="registerUser()">Register here</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've registered your route with a trailing slash, [Flask Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior).

`@app.route('/register/', methods=['POST'])`

But in your form you're posting to the URL without a trailing slash:

`<form id="register" class="register-group" action="/register" method="POST">`.

You need to remove or add the trailing slash respectively.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I have tried that after checking another post but it was to no avail and I thought I have corrected all of them. Thanks for spotting that one. However, after taking the trailing slash out it still shows the same error. :(